# Compare List and Observable Collection and remove differences from Observable Collection

Tags: c#, wpf, viewmodel

I am trying to fix a problem with some existing code I am working on where an ObservableCollection is built from a List, but as items are removed from the first list (when it is regenerated from scratch) they are not removed from the ObservableCollection. The list is generated as a part of a DLL and the ObservableCollection is in a part of an exe file and the data is passed between the two by using delegate/event/invoke. The list points to a class which contains an index that can uniquely identify each instance of that class.

The code looks as follows:

**DLL**

```
public delegate void EntryListUpdateDelegate(string sender, CarInfo car);
public event EntryListUpdateDelegate OnEntrylistUpdate;

List<CarInfo> _entryListCars = new List<CarInfo>();

case InboundMessageTypes.ENTRY_LIST:
{
    _entryListCars.Clear();
    var carEntryCount = br.ReadUInt16();
    for (int i = 0; i < carEntryCount; i++)
    {
        _entryListCars.Add(new CarInfo(br.ReadUInt16()));
    }
}

case InboundMessageTypes.ENTRY_LIST_CAR:
    {
        var carId = br.ReadUInt16();
        var carInfo = _entryListCars.SingleOrDefault(x => x.CarIndex == carId);

        // ... Set attributes for car e.g. carInfo.TeamName = ReadString(br);

        OnEntrylistUpdate?.Invoke(ConnectionIdentifier, carInfo);
    }
```

At regular intervals the above code is run to recreate the entryList and keep it up to date.

The CarInfo struct looks like this:

```
public class CarInfo
{
    public ushort CarIndex { get; }
    ....
}
```

**EXE**

The data is passed from the DLL to the EXE using delegate event, the ObservableCollection is created in the ViewModel like this:

```
public ObservableCollection<CarViewModel> Cars { get; } = new ObservableCollection<CarViewModel>();

internal void RegisterNewClient(MyUdpRemoteClient newClient)
{
    if (newClient.MsRealtimeUpdateInterval > 0)
    {
        // This client will send realtime updates, we should listen
        newClient.MessageHandler.OnTrackDataUpdate += MessageHandler_OnTrackDataUpdate;
        newClient.MessageHandler.OnEntrylistUpdate += MessageHandler_OnEntrylistUpdate;
        newClient.MessageHandler.OnRealtimeUpdate += MessageHandler_OnRealtimeUpdate;
        newClient.MessageHandler.OnRealtimeCarUpdate += MessageHandler_OnRealtimeCarUpdate;
    }

    _clients.Add(newClient.MessageHandler);
}

private void MessageHandler_OnEntrylistUpdate(string sender, CarInfo carUpdate)
{
    CarViewModel vm = Cars.SingleOrDefault(x => x.CarIndex == carUpdate.CarIndex);
    if (vm == null)
    {
        vm = new CarViewModel(carUpdate.CarIndex);
        Cars.Add(vm);
    }
    vm.Update(carUpdate);
}
```

Cars is then used in the xaml file to display the list of Cars in an Entry List in the WPF GUI in a CollectionViewSource.

**THE PROBLEM:**

_entryListCars in the DLL is always updated and accurate as it is cleared out and reupdated every so often. New cars that come along are successfully added to the Cars ObservableCollection, but Cars that disconnect/die that are no longer a part of _entryListCars are never removed from the Cars ObservableCollection. It just keeps getting bigger and bigger and continues to display the dead/inactive cars.

**MY QUESTION:**

What is the best way to remove the dead/inactive cars from the Cars ObservableCollection? I wondered whether I would be able to compare the two lists using Except (list1.Except(list2)) and then remove all of the car entries that exist in the Cars ObservableCollection that aren't in the _entryListCars list using maybe Contains on CarIndex and Cars.Remove/RemoveAt/RemoveItem? What is the best way to achieve this and what would the code look like?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Be careful with posting code that doesn't compile - it makes it feel like important information is missing and harder to read. That being said, it seems like you're receiving a stream of data for which you are raising events. So, where is the earliest point at which you know that a car has been either updated, added or removed?

Comment: @Xerillio Sorry, I was worried about posting that extra code as I had a feeling it may cause confusion. All I really needed to show was var carInfo = _entryListCars.SingleOrDefault(x => x.CarIndex == carId); and the Invoke line so you could see what was passed. Your first answer was great and gave me some ideas. Looks like I killed the question after that as it is now closed. _entryListCars is the first thing that is populated from the data that comes in from an RequestEntryList(); request.  The two switch case statements are just responding to the incoming data from the udp  stream.

Comment: One thing that I don't know whether I can use is _clients as _entryListCars appears to be accessible from there (_clients.[0]._entryListCars.[0].CarIndex). _clients is defined as private List<BroadcastingNetworkProtocol> _clients = new List<BroadcastingNetworkProtocol>(); . BroadcastingNetworkProtocol is the class in the DLL which contains the switch/case statements I showed above.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't argue about how to handle the incoming data without knowing a bit more - perhaps that's a subject for a different question. In any case, if the data you receive tells you for each car whether it's added, removed or updated then I'd suggest creating an event for each action, otherwise if you receive the full updated list every time the event should probably pass the whole list as in my answer, depending on your needs.

Comment: @Xerillio I did end up finding a solution using _clients[x]._entryListCars and using your code below to do the detection and removal. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at you event handler `MessageHandler_OnEntrylistUpdate` the naming would indicate to me that it's expecting a list as the event arguments and not just a new `CarInfo`. So to keep that naming, one way you could "fix" this is to change the event to pass the whole list as input instead:

```
public event EventHandler<List<CarInfo>> OnEntrylistUpdate;

// ...

OnEntrylistUpdate.Invoke(_entryListCars);
```

Then in your event handler (you can probably do it smarter depending on what you need):

```
private void MessageHandler_OnEntrylistUpdate(string sender, List<CarInfo> updatedCarList)
{
    var newCars = updatedCarList
        .Where(uc => !Cars.Any(c => c.CarIndex == uc.CarIndex)
        .Select(c => new CarViewModel(c.CarIndex))
        .ToList();
    var existingCars = Cars
        .Where(c => updatedCarList.Any(uc => uc.CarIndex == c.CarIndex)
        .ToList();
    var removedCars = Cars
        .Except(existingCars)
        .ToList();

    // Do whatever you need with your cars...

    foreach (var car in newCars)
        Cars.Add(car);

    foreach (var car in removedCars)
        Cars.Remove(car);

    foreach (var car in newCars.Concat(existingCars))
        car.Update(updatedCarList.Single(uc => uc.CarIndex == car.CarIndex));
}
```

All that being said, I would suggest you look into whether you can avoid doing an update of the whole list every time and instead just add/remove/update one car at a time. This requires that your source supports this of course.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for your quick response. Sorry for my delay. It was my night...I went to bed after posting the question. I think it is just passing a single entry at a time rather than a list already. I will update the code above shortly to show you what that looks like. With the changes I post above, how does that change your suggested code?

Comment: Edits are now done to original message above

Comment: I think my last comment was unclear, sorry for that. It was my impression from your original question that the method invoking `OnEntrylistUpdate` was always using a list and then just raising the event for one car at a time. I'll add a comment to your question.